# Unvisited neigbours in graph path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am trying to find distance in an undirected graph, but when navigating to different path, the count cannot be calculated properly.

I am not sure what is the best approach for:

1) To count the path values excluding unnecessary paths.

2) To keep the path (I think to use LinkedList or ArrayList, etc.  what is the best choices for this situation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the counter doesn't count properly? Does it stay the same instead of increasing or increase when you don't want it to?

Comment: Actually I would need the suggestions about the 2 points in the question. Then I will try to fix the problem. Thanks.

Comment: 1) you can decrease the counter at the end of the recursive method when you are stepping out of a node. 2) it doesn't matter just use a List

Comment: @Bizhan Many thanks for your reply. Regarding to **1**, I can navigate properly to all of the nodes, but I am confused about building a logic to detect the unconnected nodes i.e. 3 and 4. They have no weight values, I can catch, but have no idea decreasing 3 and 4 in recursive call. Any example please?

Comment: @Bizhan Any help please?

Comment: As far as I can tell this problem would be NP-Hard. What is the actual goal here? Do you intend to use this for anything except toy-problems? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: @JonasH I have already read it, but I just confused when implementation stage. I just need to check the extended nodes (3 and 4)and decrease the counter when navigating to them (after recursive call). But have not succeded and need and example implementation :(

Comment: No repeat, and use undirected graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code that solves this problem:

```
void Measure(Node node)
{
    path.Add(node);
    node.IsVisited = true;

    if (node != destination)
    {
        foreach (var neighbor in node.Neighbors.Where(n=>!n.IsVisited))
        {
            Measure(neighbor);
        }
        path.RemoveAt(path.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

You can use any dynamic length structure such as List or LinkedList for storing the path. List is recommended for simplicity.

usage:

```
var path = new List<Node>()
Measure(firstNode);
Print(path.Count);
```

this works if there is a path between the two nodes. otherwise the path is empty.

```
class Node
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsVisited { get; set; }
     public List<Node> Neighbors { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I do not draw graphs and for this reason shall I use key-value pairs instead of Node? Or inside Node class?

Comment: On the other hand, yes I measure between two nodes. But I have no idea **node is not destination** section, because that is the point makes me confused. Any example pls?

Comment: I don't understand how these matter. I wrote a psudocode because you didn't share any code, so I assumed that you can convert that into your own structure. use any type you think is suitable for node. (I would write a new class, with name, neighbors and isVisited properties). node is not destination can be `node != destination` or `node.name != destination.name`. destination is the destination node (6)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you also add class definition? I am not sure the type of some properties.

Comment: @Jason I added the class definition